# set-Interval inside a for-loop so it repeats itself

Tags: javascript

in my JavaScript file you can see I have created a for-loop so that the `setInterval` activating the `fallingMostLeftNote()` function repeats itself 800 times, exept it is not working and I cannot figure out why. The HTML is just the one `div`, the rest is all on the JavaScript and a bit on the CSS. Thank you.

```js
var mostLeftNoteMarginTop = 0;


function fallingMostLeftNote() {
  $(".mostLeftNote").css({'margin-top':mostLeftNoteMarginTop+20 + 'px'});
}


for (i = 0; i < 800; i++){
setInterval(fallingMostLeftNote, 1000);
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}


.mostLeftNote{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DNCE</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
  
  
  
  
  
    <div class="mostLeftNote">

    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval` starts a repeating timer that calls the given function at every given interval, so you’re starting 800 timers at the same time that go off every 1000 ms at the same time. Are you trying to do something every 1000 ms up to a limit of 800 times (i.e. stop in 800 seconds)?

Comment: @Ry-♦ yes, I want to do that.

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `mostLeftNoteMarginTop` always stays the same. You actually need to increment it and *then* do any operations with it.

```js
var mostLeftNoteMarginTop = 0;


function fallingMostLeftNote() {
  mostLeftNoteMarginTop += 20
  $(".mostLeftNote").css({'margin-top':mostLeftNoteMarginTop + 'px'});
}


for (i = 0; i < 800; i++){
  setInterval(fallingMostLeftNote, 1000);
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}


.mostLeftNote{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DNCE</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
  
  
  
  
  
    <div class="mostLeftNote">

    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And as @Ry- mentioned in the comments, you also need to do something every second, up to 800 times, and your code doesn't currently do that. So, you can actually use `async function`s to do this.

```js
var mostLeftNoteMarginTop = 0;


function fallingMostLeftNote() {
  mostLeftNoteMarginTop += 20
  $(".mostLeftNote").css({'margin-top':mostLeftNoteMarginTop + 'px'});
}

async function doIt() {
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    await sleep(1000)
    fallingMostLeftNote()
  }
}

doIt()
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}


.mostLeftNote{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DNCE</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
  
  
  
  
  
    <div class="mostLeftNote">

    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, look at my answer and fix yours accordingly, your square moves way to fast down, to the point where it is not visible. I will accept your answer after using the code I wrote on my answer.

Comment: @WiseEye I also added an extra snippet at the bottom of my answer that takes advantage of asynchronous functions. It is unnecessarily complicated, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific number of repeats,and then stop you may use a different approach. Actually

```
for (i = 0; i < 800; i++){
    setInterval(fallingMostLeftNote, 1000);
}
```

Is triggering 800 simultaneous executions of `fallingMostLeftNote()` every 1 second.

You can create a single setInterval call and stop the interval (`clearInterval`) after a number of calls:

```
var counter=800;
function fallingMostLeftNote() {
  counter--;
  $(".mostLeftNote").css({'margin-top':mostLeftNoteMarginTop+20 + 'px'});
  if (counter==0){
     clearInterval(proc);
  }
}
proc=setInterval(fallingMostLeftNote, 1000);
```

Also noted the `mostLeftNoteMarginTop` variable is not changing inside the code you shared. If this variable is not changed, the position will not change anyways.